# Xamarin Prism Model to ViewModel Fody

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism, fody

how do I Intercept From Model to ViewModel using [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) ?

I tried putting this in my ViewModel but nothing happens, Am I missing something ?
**I'm Using Xamarin Forms, Prism**
**Model**

```
   public class Question : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("This Works Here :) ");
            var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
            if (propertyChanged != null)
            {
                propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INavigationAware, INotifyPropertyChanged{
        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("It Does not reach here :( ");
        }

        public static void Intercept(object target, Action onPropertyChangedAction, string propertyName)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("It Does not reach here too :( ");
            onPropertyChangedAction();
        }
}
```

Do I need to use **PropertyChangedNotificationInterceptor** ? How do I implement it in my View-Model , Any advice would be awesome

**[UPDATE]**

[Sample of Repo here](https://github.com/leroygumede/XamarinFormsFody)

Comment: Ensure that you have a Weavers.xml in your targeting platform projects with <PropertyChanged /> in it.

Comment: I have a typo in the previous comment, the xml file name should be: "FodyWeavers.xml". Might be related to https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues/363

Comment: @EvZ Thanks but that not it, I added a sample repo in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in fody property changed is called as easy as this :

```
public string Text{ get; set; }
public void OnTextChanged()
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Created this question when I was still a Noobie :) , I never realised that you had to make the Modal itself Bindable